# Prove an identity in measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory

Let v be a measure on B([0,$\infty$)) such that N(u) = v([0,u)) < $\infty$, for all u $\in$ R. Let (S, $S$, $\mu$) be a σ-finite measure space. For f $\in$ $L^0_+(S)$ show that

1. $\int$ N ∘ f $du$ = $\int_{[0, \infty)}$ $\mu$({f > u})v(du).
2. For p > 0, we have $\int f^p d\mu$ = p $\int_{[0, \infty)} u^{p-1} \mu(${f>u}$)\lambda(du) $

I have no clue where to begin with this problem. Since I'm swapping around measures, I thought I might use Fubini-Tonitelli, but I don't know how to implement it in this theorem.

Comment: What do you mean with $N$?

Comment: What is $L_+^0(S)$?

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides It's a definition.

Comment: $L^0_+(S)$ is set of nonnegative measurable functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_S N\circ f\,d\mu
&= \int_S\nu([0,f(s)))\,d\mu = \int_S\int_0^{f(s)-}\,d\nu\,d\mu = \int_S\int_0^\infty\chi_{[0,f(s))}(u)\,d\nu\,d\mu\\
&= \int_0^\infty\int_S \chi_{[0,f(s))}(u)\,d\mu(s)\,d\nu(u) = \int_0^\infty\int_S \chi_{f^{-1}((u,\infty))}(s)\,d\mu(s)\,d\nu(u)\\
&= \int_0^\infty\mu(f^{-1}((u,\infty)))\,d\nu = \int_0^\infty\mu(\{f>u\})\,d\nu.
\end{align}